# Is it possible to register a node in Corda network on the fly

Tags: corda

We have a use case wherein we have a network of nodes and a new node needs to enter that network map. Is there a way we can register the node with that network map on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Start the new node and it will register with the network map and be contactable.

Comment: I wanted to do something like in demo bench, wherein we can just click on "Add Node" button and it gets added. Could you please share an example code?